# Rails - How to refuse bad formatted params - ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, httpwebresponse

In order to improve the security of my app I want to be able to check the received parameters in my Application Controller.

**ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError**

exemple :

```
"unexpected token at" ...
params 
  {
    string: "string good formated",
    interger1: 12,
    intergerBad:34/../WEB-INF/web.xml340
  }
```

When I receive that, I get an error of bad formatted json, but I want to handle this error in my application controller.

Any ideas ?

Comment: create a class, include active model validation, add your validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want achieve is tricky. A parameter is nothing else than a String. It may contain several different types of data: primitive values such as strings or integers, or even complex data.

However, what they actually mean is a business logic that depends on your application and the meaning you give them. With this interpretation in mind, even "Bad formatted" parameter is in your case business definition.

The reason I'm telling you that is because you are making an assumption can you could check these parameters in the ApplicationController, however the place where you would probably check them is the specific controller that uses a parameter.

In fact, the same `:id` parameter may represent an integer in the User controller and a string in the Whatever controller.

One more reason ApplicationController is not the best place to check it is because you are in a kind of middle place. If you want to squeeze performance and not even load the entire Rails stack, then use a Middleware. It's fast, cheap and inexpensive, but as the ApplicationController, it requires you to know in advance what kind of data will be stored in each single parameter. And there might be ambiguous parameters.

Conversely, you can check them (as it is normally done) in the specific controller where you expect the value to be used.

In my opinion you are looking for a one solution to rule them all, whereas unfortunately an application development may require a little bit of extra effort an customization.

If you do have some super sensitive parameter that you can unambiguously validate as soon as the request comes in, then use a Rack Middleware.

Comment: I see, but I've just EDIT my question,
I've got an exception on my server : ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError - 
I don't want to have this, I want to return a simple BadRequest

Comment: In that case, simply use a Middleware to either (1) rescue the error or (2) validate the input according to the rules that caused the exception. I'm doing the same for instance to validate API requests where I expect the payload to always be a valid JSON. I'll then delegate the specific parameter validation down to the controller.